# Passing serialized object between applications

Tags: android, serialization, kotlin

I'm trying to pass a serialized object between applications using a Bundle, where in one app the object is in Java whereas in the other app the same object is in Kotlin.

**Passing an object -**

```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
    bundle.putSerializable(Constants.KEY_USER_PROFILE, getUserProfile());
```

**For Fetching an Object -**

```
 Profile profile = (Profile) bundle.getSerializable(Constants.KEY_USER_PROFILE);
```

In second case profile class is in kotlin language whereas in first it is in java

**I'm getting following exception while passing an object**

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = base.model.user.Profile)
                                                                                                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = base.model.user.Profile)

```
                                                                           Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: base.model.user.Profile; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7285398503547917474, local class serialVersionUID = -1011142074531890510
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the serialVersionUID is different in both the cases, It should be the same in serialized and deserialized class for serialization to work. Put this line in both of your classes

```
public static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
```